# Ciclo de vida de un FormRequest Laravel

Tags: laravel, formrequest

¿Cuál es el orden de llamada de los métodos de un ***FormRequest Laravel***?

Necesito inicializar propiedades en un FormRequest de Laravel.

Voy a usar una serie de valores que recupero de un fichero de configuración en los métodos `rules()` y `messages()` de un [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html) en Laravel.

No quiero hacer cada llamada en cada uno de estos métodos sino inicializar propiedades de la clase, ¿lo hago en el *contructor* o hay algún otro método "adecuado", que se llame antes de las *reglas* y los *mensajes*? Por ejemplo, ¿`authorize()`?

Intuyo que el orden de llamada sería:

```
 - constructor()
 - authorize()
 - rules()
 - messages()
```

pero no encuentro información...

Comment: El método [prepareForValidation](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html#method_prepareForValidation) se ejecuta antes de rules y messages

Answer (score 0):

Los métodos que se ejecutan en un [Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html), en *Laravel*, siguen cierto orden o *ciclo de vida*, los listo de principio a fin y en dos grupos.

1. Métodos que se ejecutan antes de la validación:

   - __constructor()
   - prepareForValidation()
   - authorize()
   - rules()
   - messages()
2. Métodos que se ejecutan después de la validación:

   - failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator): void
   - passedValidation(): void
   - validated(): array

Los dos primeros son alternativos, se llega a uno u otro segun el resultado.
`validated()` se ejecutataría después de `passedValidation()` en su caso y es util para introducir contenido en el array de datos ya validados, p.e. introduzco una marca de tiempo:

```
public function validated(): array
{
    return array_merge(
        parent::validated(), 
        [
            'time' => time(),
        ]
    );
}
```

Dentro de `__constructor()` la *request* aun no esta disponible, es decir:

```
public function __construct()
{
        dd($this->all());
}
```

arroja un error 500. No así en cualquier otro método.

*Despúes de tratar de validar los datos de acuerdo a las reglas indicadas podemos capturar el flujo bien en `failedValidation()` o en `passedValidation()` según el resultado.*